# Firebase hosting - wasm streaming compile failed

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-hosting, unity-webgl

I used to host my Unity WebGL build on an Apache server and used a .htaccess file to enable WASM streaming and serve .unityweb files as gzip, but I now switched to Firebase Hosting and want to reenable this functionality.

This is my firebase.json file:

```
"hosting": {
  "public": "public",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "**/*.@(unityweb|wasm)",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Content-Encoding",
          "value": "gzip"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "source": "**/*.@(wasm)",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Content-Type",
          "value": "application/wasm"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "source": "application/wasm",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Add-Output-Filter-By-Type",
          "value": "DEFLATE"
        }
      ]
    } 
  ]
}
```

which should function the same as this .htaccess file:

```
AddEncoding gzip .unityweb
AddType application/wasm .wasm
AddEncoding gzip .wasm
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/wasm
```

My build functions without enabling wasm streaming in unity, but when I do, together with this firebase.json setup, I get the following errors:

```
UnityLoader.js:4 wasm streaming compile failed: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 1f 8b 08 18 @+0

UnityLoader.js:4 falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation

UnityLoader.js:4 failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 1f 8b 08 18 @+0

CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 1f 8b 08 18 @+0

UnityLoader.js:4 CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 1f 8b 08 18 @+0
```

I previously got this error when I did not configure the .htaccess file on Apache.

I am trying to host .unityweb files as gzip because of the following message from my Unity builds: `You can reduce your startup time if you configure your web server to host .unityweb files using gzip compression`.

Does anyone know how to get Firebase to do this?

Comment: How big is the whole project build for the webserver?

Comment: Currently about 15MB.

Comment: then dont bother compressing it,  thats tiny + the biggest likely is your assets which unity has compressed anyway

Comment: that's fair, but how about the WebAssembly Streaming part? or is that also just compression?

Comment: From what I understand, you are trying to force compression on those file types, is that correct? Firebase Hosting automatically serves content compressed, so if there is no other use for those headers, try without them.